# Проблема с видимостью переменных DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, kotlin

Есть код, вызывающий DatePickerDialog, ранее объявляются переменные. В функции переменные видятся, им присваивается выбранная дата. После dpd.show(), компилятор не видит, что этим переменным уже присваивались значения и на строчке
result = bD+bM+bY выдает ошибку  - Variable 'bD' must be initialized
Вот код:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        //Calendar
        var bY: String ;var bM: String ; var bD: String ; var strBirth: String
        var result: String
        val c = Calendar.getInstance()
        val year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        val month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        val day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        val btnDate = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnDate)
        val tvBirthDate = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvBirthDate)

        btnDate.setOnClickListener{
            val dpd = DatePickerDialog(this, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { DatePicker, mYear, mMonth, mDay ->
                bY = mYear.toString()  ;  bM = (mMonth+1).toString() ;  bD = mDay.toString()
                if (bD.length<2) bD ="0" + bD
                if (bM.length<2) bM = "0" + bM
                strBirth = bD +"." + bM + "." + bY
                tvBirthDate.setText(strBirth)
            },year, month,day)
            //show dialog
            dpd.show()
            result = bD+bM+bY
```

Comment: метку android-studio используйте пожалуйста с вопросами непосредственно связанными с IDE, android-разработка помечается с меткой android

Comment: у вас значение для переменной `result` присваивается на каждое нажатие, но до выбора даты, попробуйте переместить это присвоение например после установки текста в виджет, то есть после  `tvBirthDate.setText(strBirth)` иначе у вас на каждый клик будет оно падать. у вас переменная bD  получает свое значение в методе OnDateSetListener а если вы ничего не выберите или ещё что-то произойдёт, то приложение упадёт.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема понятна. После dpd.show() окошко выбора даты отобразилось, пользователь еще не выбрал дату, не нажал в нем ОК, поэтому обработчик нажатия ОК в DatePickerDialog не отработал и значения переменных не изменились. А код после dpd.show() продолжился и понятно, что значения переменных пока пусты. Выход- поменять порядок кода, надо подумать как.

Answer (score -1):

Объявите сначала переменные

```
        bD = ""
        bM = ""
        bY = ""
        btnDate.setOnClickListener{
        val dpd = DatePickerDialog(this, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { DatePicker, mYear, mMonth, mDay ->
            bY = mYear.toString()  ;  bM = (mMonth+1).toString() ;  bD = mDay.toString()
            if (bD.length<2) bD ="0" + bD
            if (bM.length<2) bM = "0" + bM
            strBirth = bD +"." + bM + "." + bY
            tvBirthDate.setText(strBirth)
        },year, month,day)
        //show dialog
        dpd.show()
        result = bD+bM+bY
```

Comment: А у автора они как обьявлены?

Comment: Перенес объявления переменных в обработчик нажатия кнопки, ошибка та же. Хотя переменные  bD, bM, bD получили значение в функции DatePickerDialog и значение отразилось в textView( tvBirthDate.setText(strBirth) ), потом после отработки DatePickerDialog (после show()), компилятор все равно пишет, что переменным не присваивались значения и нечего сложить в result.

Comment: @ArtyMorris, обьявление и инициализация -- разные вещи. В приведенном вами коде только одно обьявление -- `val dpd`.